How can we implement the CDC (Change Data Capture) in the Apache Spark?
I want to take out the difference between previous day and current day data using Apache Spark (using Python). I am newbie in it. Any help in this regard will be helpful ?
Installed the Apache Spark and read the CSV (Previous Day in PySpark)

Firstly I assume you have Apache Spark Installed on your PC along with Python 3.
After setting up your venv you need to install the pyspark package using pip command
Next after get as spark session using SparkSession. Now it is about time to read the csv files for current
old_df = spark.read.csv("/data/2024-02-01.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
new_df = spark.read.csv("/data/2024-02-02.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)

After that you might need to join that data frame. You can using join function for that based upon the column you wish to join.
Finally call the withColumn function with difference parameter to get the changes in columns you are interested.
Hope this helps. If you still get any error please do share the error.

I assume that the data doesn't consists of any last modified date and the schema of both CSV's matches. Also it should contain "id" unique column which can be used to distinguish the difference between the data of two days.
Let's move to the solution, to implement change data capture using pyspark you will need to find entries which are new or updated and the entries which are outdated.
Reading data using spark :
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

yesterdays_data = glueContext.read.csv("/data/2024-12-15.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
todays_data = glueContext.read.csv("/data/2024-12-16.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)

Firstly, find entries which are new or updated :
df_to_insert = todays_data.join(
    yesterdays_data,
    todays_data.id == yesterdays_data.id,
    "left_anti",
)

Now, let's find entries to be deleted which are outdated :
df_to_delete = yesterdays_data.join(
    todays_data,
    yesterdays_data.id == todays_data.id,
    "left_anti",
)

I hope this will help you to implement change data capture.
